# How much does the earth's axis change its tilt every year?

Tags: earth, sunlight

In recent years it seems that the winter sun rises and sets even further south as parts of my house are illuminated with sunlight that I don't recall 4 or 5 years ago.

Comment: This question is best suited for the Astronomy Stack Exchange Site.

Comment: [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) or [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/). But first check those two for existing questions and answers about the Earth's axis. Short answer; the Earth's axis does change, but *very very slowly*, way too slowly to do anything noticeable like this. People who watch the Sun's motion throughout the year by making an [Analemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analemma) type shapes either using photography or just plotting the position of the shadow of a fixed object at clock noon over a year will see the same pattern every year.

Comment: You can also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt#Oscillation where the leading term in the expansion is about *47 arcseconds per century!*

Comment: see [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/18186/7982) in Astronomy SE for example.

Comment: Thank you, StarMan and uhoh!